# Perforce best practices with Branching

Tags: perforce

I'm a bit new at using perforce and was wondering what I should/shouldn't do...
I don't have too much experience with the idea of branching out and I find myself looking through labels for past versions and bug fixes.

By the way my current setup is Perforce 2009.1 and visual studio 2008.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general branching strategy is to create a branch for mainline, a branch for dev and a branch for each release. Each branch allows for another line of development. The idea is that bugfixes will be made against the release branches, and then reverse integrated or "merged" into mainline / dev. Eventually, on a next release, dev will be integrated to mainline, etc.

The best thing to keep in mind with branches/integration is to always maintain a parent/child relationship with branches, going beyond that and integrating sibling branches can be computation expensive.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Besides what Blaskovicz said, I can also recommend the chapter on Codelines and Branching in the [Perforce Manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/06_codemgmt.html).

Answer (score 1):

A Perforce consultant wrote a fairly short presentation called the Perforce Directory Standard, which gives pretty concrete examples of branching models to use for different styles of development and release maintenance.

https://www.perforce.com/blog/100607/perforce-directory-standard-pds

Comment: It looks like the URL for that blog entry has not survived, but I think this might be the new URL: http://www.perforce.com/blog/100607/perforce-directory-standard-pds

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a number of helpful guidelines about getting the most out of Perforce here in the book Practical Perforce: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101855.do